# Error when using a switch in a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Basically what I'm trying to do is to return the results of a for loop in a dataframe using also a switch.

Basically I have a table I call echelle_dommage

it looks likes

```
1 0
2 120000
3 225000
...
10 225000
```

And I have a vector called scenario1 I obtain using a sample

```
1 6 1 0 0 1 1 4 3 .....
```

Basically for every value in scenario1 (the sample) I want to return the matching value from echelle_dommage in a dataframe

For example, 
The first value of scenario1 is 1, 
so the first value in my dataframe would be 0 
The next value is 6 
so the second value in my dataframe would be 225000

```
echelle_dommage=data.frame(c(0,120000,rep(225000,times=8)))
scenario1=sample(0:9,25,replace=TRUE,prob=prob)
tableau_resume=as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=25,nrow=1))

for (i in (1:25)){
   indice=scenario1[i]
tableau_resume[,i]=switch(indice,"0"=echelle_dommage[1,1],"1"=echelle_dommage[1,2],"2"=echelle_dommage[1,3],"3"=echelle_dommage[1,4],"4"=echelle_dommage[1,5],"5"=echelle_dommage[1,6],"6"=echelle_dommage[1,7],"7"=echelle_dommage[1,8],"8"=echelle_dommage[1,9],"9"=echelle_dommage[1,10])
  }
```

Using my code I always get the error "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = 0) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns "

Any help is appreciated , thanks

Comment: A quicker way to do this would be `tableau_resume = as.data.frame(matrix(echelle_dommage[scenario1 + 1, 1], nrow = 1))` No loop or switch is needed. (Switching the way you are indexing rows and columns, as explained below)

Comment: The `switch` function does not work by itself for me. You should check that before trying it inside another function.

Comment: But I think your main problem is that you are indexing `echelle_dommage` as `[column, row]`, which is wrong. Indexes are always `echelle_dommage[row, column]`. The sample data you show `echelle_dommage` has only two columns. But your code, e.g., `"2"=echelle_dommage[1,3]`, tries to pull a value from the 3rd column.

Comment: Using a for-loop, couldn't we just `for(i in (1:25)){
  tableau_resume[,i] = echelle_dommage[scenario1[i], ]}`?

Comment: @schwantke no for loop needed, see my first comment. (And you need to add 1, because `scenario1` is 0-indexed.)

Comment: @Gregor Using `echelle_dommage=data.frame(c(0,120000,rep(225000,times=8)))
scenario1=sample(0:9,25,replace=TRUE)
tableau_resume=as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=25,nrow=1))

tableau_resume[ , 1:25] <- echelle_dommage[scenario1[1:25], ]` gives me an error because some scenarios happen more than one time

Comment: @schwantke I don't know why you changed my code. If I run your data set-up, creating `echelle_dommage` and`scenario1`, then copy/paste the command from my first comment, `tableau_resume = as.data.frame(matrix(echelle_dommage[scenario1 + 1, 1], nrow = 1))`, it works just fine. The error in your version is because you didn't add 1 to `scenario1`, so the 0s cause problems, not because certain scenarios happen more than one time.

Comment: @Jng please clarify the desired result as well. In your text, you say *"The first value of scenario1 is 1, so the first value in my dataframe would be 0"*. But that leaves confusion as to what to do when `scenario1`  is `0`. Your code "adds 1" to `scenario1`, `"0"` corresponds to `1`, "3" corresponds to `4`, etc. Can we assume your code is right and your text is wrong, for this?

Answer (score 0):

No loop or `switch` is needed. Here is a vectorized solution:

```
## sample data courtesy of @schwantke
set.seed(47)
echelle_dommage=data.frame(c(0,120000,rep(225000,times=8))) scenario1=sample(0:9,25,replace=TRUE) 

## one-line solution
tableau_resume = as.data.frame(matrix(echelle_dommage[scenario1 + 1, 1], nrow = 1))
tableau_resume
#       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9    V10    V11    V12    V13    V14    V15
# 1 225000 225000 225000 225000 225000 225000 225000 225000 225000 225000 120000 225000 120000 225000 225000
#      V16    V17 V18 V19    V20    V21    V22    V23    V24    V25
# 1 225000 225000   0   0 225000 120000 225000 225000 120000 225000
```

There is inconsistency in your question. In your text, you say *"The first value of scenario1 is 1, so the first value in my dataframe would be 0"*. But that leaves confusion as to what to do when `scenario1`  is `0`. Your code "adds 1" to `scenario1`, `"0"` corresponds to `1`, "3" corresponds to `4`, etc. I have assumed your code is correct and your text is wrong in this aspect.